# Use of koalas instead of pandas for numpy where function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spark-koalas

I am new to koalas. I have been told to implement koalas instead of pandas in my work.
Earlier when we have dataframe we convert that to pandas and use that for `np.where` with condition check inside. Example in pandas we used to do like

```py
np.where(condition,action1,action2)
```

When I try to use koalas for the same we get error below

> PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead.

I even tried `ks.series` and `ks.dataframe` but the error didn't go.

Is there any method/function in koalas to accept 3 params (condition,action1,action2) like we use `np.where` in pandas. It will be much helpful if anyone explains through example too.

Comment: Can [`where`](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.Series.where.html?highlight=where) be of some help? There are only 2 input params, but it gets close to a `np.where`

Comment: Can u pls provide a example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution similar to `np.where` is to create a function yourself (like below) that uses koalas' [`where`](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.Series.where.html?highlight=where):

```
import databricks.koalas as ks


# sample dataframe
df = ks.DataFrame({
  'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  'cost': [5000, 4000, 3000, 4500, 2000],
  'class': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
})


# your custom function
def numpy_where(s, cond, action1, action2):
  return s.where(cond, action2).where(~cond, action1)


# create sample new column
df['new_col'] = numpy_where(df['class'], df['class'] == 'A', 'yes', 'no')
print(df)
#    id  cost class new_col
# 0   1  5000     A     yes
# 1   2  4000     A     yes
# 2   3  3000     B      no
# 3   4  4500     C      no
# 4   5  2000     A     yes
```

Basically:

- `s` is the `ks.Series` on which you compute the where
- `cond` is the condition to be satisfied
- `action1` is the value to be inserted when `cond` is true
- `action2` is the value to be inserted when `cond` is false